# Triangular shaped buttons for iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, graphics

I have created a scoring system for iPad for darts (501, 701 etc) which works nicely and you can select the score that you hit using a list (20, Triples, Doubles) etc and all is working fine but I wanted to rather make it that you have an image of a dart board and simply touch the part of the board that you want to log the score.

Is it possible to have one large image of the dart board and have "hot spots", much like an HTML image map or would it be better to create a custom button for each selectable area?

Would Cocos2d be better for this system?

Many thanks for any advice on how to best to proceed.

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an image of a dartboard, and add a tap gesture recognizer to it. Rather than defining "hot spots", you would use the recognizer's locationInView property to get the location of the tap, and use some trigonometry to figure out what "pie slice" the touch was in.

Comment: Many thanks rdelmar. Had to do some research on how to achieve this as I am not a maths boffin but gave me enough to get sorted. Appreciate the help.